# The indentation in IE6 and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a problem with the site http://www.kotoki.ru . If you go to the home page in IE6 or Google Chrome, then we can note from the top margin (which is not clear where did) as soon go to the page http://kotoki.ru/moony/ margin disappears. Why is this and how to get rid of it on the main page kotoki.ru ? I tried to solve the problem himself, using firebug, but nothing succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Change the encoding of your index file to `UTF-8`. The empty line at the top is there because of the [UTF-8 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) being rendered in the screen.

If, in Firefox, you change the encoding to "Western ISO-8859-1" you will see the same margin with the UTF-8 byte order marked being rendered in the screen. Now in Chrome and IE6 the actual characters aren't there, but the margin is, so somehow the browser thinks that your document is not UTF-8 and renders the byte order mark.

<strike>Also a thing I noticed is that one of your meta tags has attributes with single quotes `'`, which is not allowed in XHTML, attributes should have double quotes `"`.</strike>

Comment: Thank you Bazzz) I'm not quite sure what I need to do

Comment: @Evgeniy - the index file has two BOMs at the start of it. You need to remove one of them, i.e. remove the first three **bytes** of the file. How you do this depends on your editor. You may find it easier to use a hex editor to do this. (Also, what Bazzz says about attribute values in single quotes is not correct).

Comment: I looked up the quote statement and agree that I was wrong. I stand corrected. :) Out of habit I always use `"`, but indeed `'` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox there is no problem with either margin, however it could be the way you've used the CSS, I would suggest having a reset CSS that runs before you main stylesheet.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

It helps reduce browser inconsistencies, hope this helps.

Comment: Put this css reset code. The indentation was only half as much, but it has not disappeared.